# Print out line number of a text?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Are there any way to print out the text line number in outputs?

I have a sample text (the first 3 sentences):

```
There was no possibility of taking a walk that day

We had been wandering indeed in the leafless shrubbery an hour in the morning but since dinner (Mrs 
Reed when there was no company dined early) the cold winter wind had brought with it clouds so sombre 
and a rain so penetrating that further out door exercise was now out of the question

I was glad of it I never liked long walks especially on chilly afternoons dreadful to me was the 
coming home in the raw twilight with nipped fingers and toes and a heart saddened by the chidings of 
Bessie the nurse and humbled by the consciousness of my physical inferiority to Eliza John and 
Georgiana Reed
```

I currently got this output:

```
9 out of 10 words contain no 'e'.
30 out of 53 words contain no 'e'.
31 out of 56 words contain no 'e'.
```

But i can't find a way to also include the line numbers at the beginning such as:

```
0: 9 out of 10 words contain no 'e'.
1: 30 out of 53 words contain no 'e'.
2: 31 out of 56 words contain no 'e'.
```

The codes (Tried using enumerate(line) but doesn't work):

```
with open("jane_eyre_sentences.txt") as line:
     low = line.lower()
     words = low.split()
     app = []
     for word in words:
        if "e" not in word:
             app.append(word)
        print("%d:%s"%(i, wordy) + "" + str(len(app)) + " out of " + str(len(words)) + " words contain no 'e'." )
```

Thanks for reading.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("jane_eyre_sentences.txt") as file:
read_file = file.readlines()
for i, word in enumerate(read_file):
    low = word.lower()
    words = low.split()
    app = [w for w in words if 'e' not in w]
    print("{}: {} out of {} words contain no 'e'.".format(i, len(app), len(words)))
```

Answer (score 3):

What you call `line` is in fact the file - not a text line.

Doing `low = line.lower()` on it should not even work:

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError
> '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'lower'

Try

```
with open("jane_eyre_sentences.txt") as file:
    for nr, line in enumerate(file): 
        words = line.lower().split()
        words_without_e = [ w for w in words if 'e' not in w]

        print(f"{nr}: {len(words_without_e)} out of {len(words)} words contain no 'e'.")
```

Output:

```
0: 9 out of 10 words contain no 'e'.
1: 0 out of 0 words contain no 'e'.
2: 8 out of 18 words contain no 'e'.
3: 11 out of 19 words contain no 'e'.
4: 11 out of 16 words contain no 'e'.
5: 0 out of 0 words contain no 'e'.
6: 12 out of 19 words contain no 'e'.
7: 11 out of 19 words contain no 'e'.
8: 8 out of 16 words contain no 'e'.
9: 0 out of 2 words contain no 'e'.
```

---

I used

```
with open("jane_eyre_sentences.txt","w") as file:
    file.write("""There was no possibility of taking a walk that day

We had been wandering indeed in the leafless shrubbery an hour in the morning but since dinner (Mrs 
Reed when there was no company dined early) the cold winter wind had brought with it clouds so sombre 
and a rain so penetrating that further out door exercise was now out of the question

I was glad of it I never liked long walks especially on chilly afternoons dreadful to me was the 
coming home in the raw twilight with nipped fingers and toes and a heart saddened by the chidings of 
Bessie the nurse and humbled by the consciousness of my physical inferiority to Eliza John and 
Georgiana Reed""")
```

as input file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, for checking out the next, you should use `readlines()`, and then iterate over your lines, like this:

```
with open('jane_eyre_sentences.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    lines = myfile.readlines()

for line in lines:
    if 'this' in line: #Your criteria here to skip lines
        continue

    #Do something here
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the one-liner solution, but you could make yourself a handy `NumberedLineWriter` class that puts a line number at the start of every line. You can then put it into a module and reuse this in any code that needs it.

```
class NumberedLineWriter:

    def __init__(self, first=0):
        self.i = first

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.i, *args, **kwargs)
        self.i += 1

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(*_):
        pass
```

Maybe put it in its own module `linewriter.py` and then when you need it you can do:

```
from linewriter import NumberedLineWriter
```

Then when you want to use it, you can just use an instance of it in place of regular `print` inside a `with` block, for example:

```
with NumberedLineWriter() as myprint:
    myprint("hello")
    myprint("world")
```

Prints

```
0 hello
1 world
```

Or in this case, combine the `with` clauses into one:

```
with open('jane_eyre_sentences.txt', 'r') as file, NumberedLineWriter() as myprint:
    for line in file:
        ....
        myprint(...whatever...)
```

It doesn't matter how many or few times you call `myprint` inside each iteration of your `for` loop, because the `myprint` contains its own counter to keep track of the line number, and is not tied into your `file` iterator in any way.